# cannot update wpf control from non UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

I know this was answered but i can't get it to work. can someone be kind enough to help me figure this out

Here's my xaml class:

```
namespace Windamow
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for DynamoWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class DynamoWindow : Window
{
    public DynamoWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void setBrowserURL(string URL)
    {
        browser.Source = new Uri(URL);
    }
    public void setBrowserFromString(string HTMLString)
    {
        browser.NavigateToString(HTMLString);
    }
}
}
```

I then try to update the html string that gets displayed like this:

```
namespace Windamow
{
public class Windamow
{

    private DynamoWindow window;

    internal void ThreadProc()
    {
        window = new DynamoWindow();

        window.ShowDialog();
    }

    internal Windamow()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }

    public static DynamoWindow MakeWindow(bool launch, string html)
    {
        if (launch)
        {
            Windamow mow = new Windamow();

            var action = new Action(() => mow.window.setBrowserFromString(html));
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Input,
            action);

            return mow.window;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Windamow.DynamoWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="browser" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Error message:

**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**

Comment: Where is the associated xaml?

Comment: @isi updated the question. my bad

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
var action = new Action(() => mow.window.setBrowserFromString(html));
```

This code will try to access the `window` object from the **main UI thread** whereas it has been created on and associated to another thread, the one you create yourself `t`.

Depending on your use case you may simply try something like:

```
public DynamoWindow(string html)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    setBrowserFromString(html);
}
...
if (launch)
{
    Windamow mow = new Windamow(html);

    return mow.window;
}
```

(not tested but you get the idea)